# edges appear in object mode in viewport after texture painting

Tags: texturing, uv, 3d-view, texture-painting

After using the texture paint the edges of the mesh become visible in viewport in object mode. These edges don't show up in solid mode, but they do in every other texture mode.
I've checked the UV map to make sure the edges are fully covered. The edges also show up around parts that have no white around it at all on the UV map.
These white edges become more and more clear the further you zoom out and completely disappear if you get close. How can I make it so these edges don't show in object mode?
[image: no edges while zoomed in]
[image: edges while zoomed out]
[image: UVMap]

Answer (score 0):

Same problem in a different topic ([link](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/276895/))

**Solution:**

1. go to *Shader Editor*
2. change texture interpolation from *Linear* (default) to *Closest* (check the picture below)

[image]

**Explanation** from other topic:

The problem is caused by the interpolation caused by mipmaping. Linear interpolation kind of blurs the image causing the colors at the edges of the UV islands to blend thus making the seams show up.

If you are not going to export the model with the texture then the proposed solution above works perfectly. For all other cases turn up the bleeding when painting or scale down a bit your UVs when editing.

[image]

More info about bleeding if you are not yet familiar with it can be found [here](https://youtu.be/9OVvnOh2ZGk?t=515) at 8:35.