# Seams on texture become visible only when zooming out

Tags: texturing, uv, shaders, seams

I have a model with a texture applied and this is what happens when the model is viewed from far away :

[image]

[image]

There are those white lines visible where the seams are but only when viewed from far enough, upclose, no seam is visible at all. My UVs have enough margin so I really don't know what is causing this.

[image]

The only thing I know is that they are only visible in realtime renderers. They are not visible in Cycles render view. They are also visible when the model is exported as a GLTF and viewed in a GLTF viewer.

Is there a way to fix/avoid this?

[image]

Comment: don't ask me where i saw this, but there was a tutorial i saw and he said, you have to "paint a bit over" the UVs so you don't get problems. So if you scale your UV down a bit like this [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/d0ZYv.jpg it works.

Comment: found it: explanation here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OVvnOh2ZGk. at 8:35

Comment: Oh. Thank you. That's actually odd. I thought the margin I had was already sufficient.

Comment: i didn't know that too - one reason more why i watch a lot of tutorials :D

Comment: Does setting the texture to 'Closest' texel instead of linear interpolation cover your cases?

Comment: @RobinBetts, thank you. That actually solved it without having to scale the UVs. The problem is caused by the interpolation caused by mipmaping. Linear interpolation kind of blurs the image causing the colors at the edges of the UV islands to blend thus making the seams show up. Seting it to 'closest' solves it for blender but for models that need to be exported, Chris' solution is what works. In my case, I just need to turn up the bleeding when painting.

Comment: Glad it's solved! Maybe @Chris should post his solution :)

Comment: Both should be posted, I think. It really depends on the use case